# Assign lookup result into array with better performance

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a look up which return json like below

```
{
    "count": 562,
    "value": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
        },
        {
            "ID": 2
        },
```

I would like to save it into a variable array of int, the only method I found is to loop the json value array with `forearch` and then append `@item().ID` to the array. Although this is working it will take over 1 minute for just 5xx records, which is far too slow.

Would like to know if there are method with better performance?

Answer (score 1):

@Bill,
Ofcourse this is not a direct answer as I couldnt find another way to do this withnin ADF. But if your Lookup is SQL, then you can return a comma seperated string as below and then convert it to an array.

```
select string_agg(t.DeviceId,', ') as DeviceIds
 from (select distinct DeviceId from DevicesTable where CustomerId = 1) as t
```

Output:

```
72, 127, 177, 200, 201
```